# Viewing Server-Sent Events in Firefox

Tags: firefox, web-development, html5, api

[SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) is a simple and straight-forward alternative to WebSockets when you need a one-way channel for events coming from the server.

In Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab, you can click the resource (url) where the SSE originates from and [view the stream in a tab of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46075339/200987). I cannot seem to find this functionality in Firefox.

Is there a simple way of viewing server-sent events in Firefox, that doesn't require me to change the source code (inserting logging statements)?

Comment: have you found any solution for this question ?

Comment: No, I have not, @bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 82 and onwards [should be able](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Inspecting_server-sent_events) to show SSE messages in the Network > Response tab of the file which is sending those events.